I took a summer research intership and didn't do well after, what should I do?
I applied for a summer internship(no salary) in theoretical physics a few months ago, and I got one intership position. After I got the work to be done from the professor, I found that some parts of the project is hard for me to understand, so I ask the professor about it. Only after more than 2 emails did he respond to me with very few instruction, which also helps little. He basically replies 1 time when I sent 2 emails to him, so I finally decide to quit. Since I cannot get vaulable instruction from him. 
I want to know is what I did right? Is what I did offending to him? Because I just stop working on it and never contact him again(he didn't ask me either). Should I write an email to say I am sorry this don't work out well?\

"so I finally decide to quit" "I just stop working on it and never contact him again" Did you actually tell them you quit or did you literally just stop working? In other words, are they aware you quit or are they waiting for your next update?

No, I didn't tell them. The professor tell me to contact him again once I figure out the tool for the project, but I failed on that. And just never contacted him. Since there is no group meeting or anything held weekly with which I can talk to him.

I would assume they think I quit, since I guess normally the professor would ask whats going on if he has no response from someone for months... But still, thats what I am uncertain about. I am actually feeling frustrated that time and really hate to contact him again since I think he is not willing to help.....

What is your goal? Do you want to mend your relationship with them for another internship, or because you will encounter them again in your studies? Since you mentioned only email communication, can you actually meet with them in person?

Thats possible, since I am in the same university with the prof.

When you sent your emails. Did you have specific questions? Ones that the faculty could answer to provide guidance? Did you explain what you had tried to do and where you got stuck? Emails that blankly say "I am confused, I don't know anything" are quite daunting for a busy faculty to even attempt to answer. It is clear that you lacked the knowledge to be taking part of this internship, and at the same time, the faculty lacked the time and interest in mentoring someone with so little background.

I have actually write on the tablet to explained my confusion... And he just dont respond

This seems like a very odd unpaid internship. Were you working in the same place as the prof? Were there group meetings? Or were you simply emailing each other, with (by the sound of it) no support one way and no commitment the other?

No place for working, I simply work at home and once I get some result I contact with the prof. "Or were you simply emailing each other, with (by the sound of it) no support one way and no commitment the other? " More or less the truth.

You were apparently unprepared for this internship with too little background. The professor seems unprepared to handle a student with too-little knowledge. This was a bad match, not one made in heaven, but rather...
Yes, I'd send a follow up apology letter admitting your unpreparedness and that you hope to do better with such things in future. Beyond that, there is little to do.
Depending on what paper trail was left by your "participation" you might not need to list this on any CV. If it was "for credit" and you are showing a bad grade, just be prepared to answer questions. "I was in over my head" should be understandable to most (not all) folks. A 2-3 month internship isn't a lot of time to catch up on a deep topic and make a contribution.
There is nothing disqualifying about an undergraduate or beginning masters student being unprepared for advanced work. I'm assuming here that the topic of the internship isn't something covered deeply in your program and that you should have already known the fundamentals.
For future, however, learn to use email less and personal contact more. This will be an advantage both in learning and in keeping relationships alive.

Sometimes personal contact is not possible, the prof may not be available for that. I would also add that one of the most valuable skills is to learn to ask the right questions - find those few questions that give the most information. Many profs are impatient people.

@CaptainEmacs, what you say is true enough, but it is hard for me to have respect for profs that can't make time for their interns and other advisees. And, giving complete answers to a student's email can also be time consuming and not just for the time it takes to compose it.

I was also an intern at some point. I very quickly realized that questions are numbered and focused on learning to pose the most specific and useful questions that would answer as many problems as possible at once. This is a valuable skill to develop, independently of context. Responses tend to be far more helpful, and people ready to help when they notice you've put in your own due diligence in making their job to respond easier.
